# Unable to Align a Nav to the Left

Tags: html, css, alignment, nav

If I try aligning my nav, created from an unordered list, it aligns to the absolute right, but it doesn't align to the left. It appears that there's a 20px or so gap to the left of my nav text. I took out my padding to see if there was still a gap, and yes there is. I was also wondering why my Column 1 is sitting at the bottom of its column unlike the other 2. Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:
HTML5

```css
nav{
 display: block;
 background: #007845;
 height: 25px;
 width: 100%;
}
nav ul{
 /*This effects only the ul within the nav; NO OTHER LISTS*/
 /*The next two lines send the text to the left edge*/
 margin: 0px;
}
nav ul li{
 /*This effects only the li within the ul within the nav; NO OTHER LISTS*/
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
 margin: 0px;
}
nav ul li a{
 /*This effects only the a link within the li within the ul within the nav; NO OTHER LISTS*/
 text-decoration: none;/*Gets rid of the underline*/
 float: left;
 display: block;
 color: black;
}
#container p{
 text-align: left;
 vertical-align: top;
}
#container{
 margin: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 -moz-column-count: 3;
 -moz-column-gap: 1em;
 -moz-column-rule: 1px solid black;
 -webkit-column-count: 3;
 -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
 -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid black;
 column-count: 3;
 column-gap: 1em;
 column-rule: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="ThreeColumns.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Photo</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Graphic</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="container">
    <p>Column 1</p>
    <p>Column 2</p>
    <p>Column 3</p>
  </div><!--End Container-->
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by putting margin:0 in your container p and padding:0 in your nav ul. I have spaced dout your ul a bit

```css
nav {
    display: block;
    background: #007845;
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
}
nav ul {
    /*This effects only the ul within the nav; NO OTHER LISTS*/
    /*The next two lines send the text to the left edge*/
    margin: 2px;
    padding:0;
}
nav ul li {
    /*This effects only the li within the ul within the nav; NO OTHER LISTS*/
    list-style: none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
nav ul li a {
    /*This effects only the a link within the li within the ul within the nav; NO OTHER LISTS*/
    text-decoration: none;
    /*Gets rid of the underline*/    
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
}

#container {
    margin: 0px;
   min-width: 100%;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -moz-column-rule: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid black;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 1em;
    column-rule: 1px solid black;
}
#container p {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    min-width:33%;
   
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Photo</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Graphic</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="container">
        <p>Column 1</p>
        <p>Column 2</p>
        <p>Column 3</p>
    </div>
    <!--End Container-->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the desired result? I've set `padding: 0` to `nav ul` and `margin: 0` to `#container p`

```css
nav {
  display: block;
  background: #007845;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
  /*This effects only the ul within the nav; NO OTHER LISTS*/
  /*The next two lines send the text to the left edge*/
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  /*This effects only the li within the ul within the nav; NO OTHER LISTS*/
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
}
nav ul li a {
  /*This effects only the a link within the li within the ul within the nav; NO OTHER LISTS*/
  text-decoration: none;
  /*Gets rid of the underline*/
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
}
#container p {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  -moz-column-rule: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid black;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 1em;
  column-rule: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="ThreeColumns.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Photo</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Graphic</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="container">
    <p>Column 1</p>
    <p>Column 2</p>
    <p>Column 3</p>
  </div>
  <!--End Container-->
</body>

</html>
```